# What does the amber light on the AirPods case mean when AirPods are not in the case?

Tags: battery, charging, airpods

When I take the AirPods out of their case sometimes the case light changes color from orange to green or vice versa. I know the amber light means it is either charging or needs a charge. Is it associated with a particular battery percentage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Apple's support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207012) for AirPods doesn't point to an exact percentage but rather if the case can fully charge the AirPods.

> If your AirPods are in your case, then the light shows the charge
>   status of your AirPods. If not, the light shows the status of your
>   case. Green means charged, and amber means less than one full charge
>   remains. If the light flashes white, your AirPods are ready to set up
>   with one of your devices. If the light flashes amber, you might need
>   to set up your AirPods again.

Comment: @JBallin I'd love a video to disprove Apple's support docs if you have a chance.

Answer (score 3):

**Amber** in an empty case means that the case doesn't have enough battery to fully charge a drained pair of [AirPods](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207012).

---

## (# AirPods in Case)

- (2) if both fully charged **Green** else **Amber**
- (1) if AirPod (in case) fully charged **Green** else **Amber**
- (0) if case has capacity for a full charge of drained AirPods **Green** else **Amber**

---

## Case changing color example:

**Amber** → **Green** when removing uncharged AirPods from charged case

Comment: This is not true according to Apple's docs (see my answer) and in my testing. I opened the case without AirPods next to my phone to see charge status. The light is green and the case shows 92% charged.

Comment: This answer has been updated to be correct since Steve's comment. Please share feedback when down voting posts for non-obvious reasons.